# Make Apple Watch calendar complication sync quickly with Google Calendar

Tags: calendar, apple-watch, google-calendar

I make heavy use of the calendar complication on the Apple Watch (Infograph Modular).  I use Google Calendar as the source of truth, sync those Google Calendars to the iPhone Calendar app, and then events from Google Calendar show up on the watch.

Unfortunately, when I add a new calendar entry in Google Calendar via the web app, it takes quite a long time to sync all the way to the watch.  I'm not sure how long, but at least 30 minutes sometimes.  When I notice that it hasn't synced, I can trigger a sync simply by opening the iPhone Calendar app on my phone.  After waiting for a few seconds the iPhone calendar syncs, and then the watch face updates.

Ideally I'd like changes to the Google Calendar to propagate to the watch in a couple minutes at most, without me having to do anything.  Is that possible?

Comment: What is your setting in "Refresh Calendar ... Every ? ...min"

Comment: @Buscar웃 I would love such a setting!  Where is it?  I've looked for it but failed to find one.  I'm on iOS 12.1.4, watchOS 5.1.3.

Comment: On my Mac it is in Calendar > Preference > Accounts > Google calendar > Refresh

Comment: @Ruskes I don't think the Mac one is relevant, since it needs to sync to my phone, not my Mac.  I changed it to 5 min just in case, but it doesn't seem to affect phone syncing.

Comment: Well, if your Mac syncs with your Phone and your Phone syncs with the Watch :)

Comment: My understanding, supported by my test just now, is that phone syncing of Google calendar entries doesn't happen via the Mac.  It happens via Google Calendar.  Regardless, I would prefer a solution that doesn't involve my Mac, given that I'd like this to work even if my Mac is closed (such as if I create a calendar entry on Google Calendar on my phone).

Comment: well Apple thinks so https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202337

Comment: I believe you're confusing Google Calendar with iCloud.  The question is about Google Calendar.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving Have you found a solution? Exactly the same situation happens to me now.

Comment: @Darmen Amanbayev: Nope, I still have the problem.  But if you have the problem, maybe upvote the question?

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving Done :)